# OpenVPN FreeNAS BSD installation issues

Tags: freebsd, openvpn

im following this guide to install OpenVPN on my FreeNAS system. 
http://joepaetzel.wordpress.com/2013/09/22/openvpn-on-freenas-9-1/

I have ran in to the issues detailed below when trying to create the CA.cert.

```
[root@freenas] /mnt/NAS/openvpn# chmod -R 755 easy-rsa/2.0/*
[root@freenas] /mnt/NAS/openvpn# cd easy-rsa/2.0
[root@freenas] /mnt/NAS/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0# sh
#./clean-all
Please source the vars script first (i.e. "source ./vars")
Make sure you have edited it to reflect your configuration.
# . ./vars
NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on /mnt/NAS/openvpn/easyrsa/2.0/keys
# ./build-ca
Please edit the vars script to reflect your configuration,
then source it with "source ./vars".
Next, to start with a fresh PKI configuration and to delete any
previous certificates and keys, run "./clean-all".
Finally, you can run this tool (pkitool) to build certificates/keys.
```

I have tried creating the keys directory manually as i have read this has worked for others but still no luck. Being new to BSD I've hit a road block and looking for some advice.

Any ideas?

cheers guys

UPDATE:

When trying to source ./vars i get the following output

```
[root@freenas] /mnt/NAS/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0# source ./vars
export: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
EASY_RSA: Undefined variable.
export: Command not found.
EASY_RSA: Undefined variable.
```

Comment: It looks like it expects some type of other shell environment than the one you are using... see my possible answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeNAS's default shell is not `sh`, and therefore doesn't support the 'export' command. The `./vars` script needs the `export` command to set environment variables it then needs.

So before you call `./vars` (don't call source) call:

```
sh
```

This is clearly stated in the site: http://joepaetzel.wordpress.com/2013/09/22/openvpn-on-freenas-9-1/

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped. Not sure how i missed it.

What i had to do it run 'code'./vars before ./clean-all This worked :)

Comment: is there any command i can run to make sure Openvpn is running using my vpn service once i have logged in?

Comment: You can do `ps a | grep openvpn` it should return the process name `openvpn` and its Process ID (PID), upvote my answer/choose it as an answer if it is correct

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the original issue, i think nrathaus has covered that well.

demonLaMagra - If you want to check if openvpn in running use this command:

```
service openvpn status
```

Sorry I couldn't comment on the last answer because of being a new new user, otherwise I would have.